# Mongodb query on substring of a field

Tags: mongodb, substr

I'd like to retrieve results equals to departement codes, 
but I'm storing postal codes. Something like that...

```
db.collection.find({
    {$substr:[cp,0,2]}:{$eq:dpt}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation $project to create department code column. Then find by $match your condition

```
    db.collection.aggregate(
            [ 
                { $project:{
                    "cp" : 1,
                    department_code: { $substr: ["$cp", 0, 2]}
                    }
                }
                ,{ $match : { department_code: 'department code to find' } }
            ]
        );
```